# link passing through mail php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

For user identification,I need to send the url of localhost via mail in php codeigniter . . I also need to pass the token which I had generated for that user along with the url. My user need to be verified by clicking that link which must be identified by the corresponding token. And I have no idea about passing variables via url . . How could I proceed my code?

My code follows. .

```
<?php
class Site_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }
    public function insert($token)
    { 
        $data = array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
        'date_of_birth'=>$this->input->post('dob'),
        'user_type'=>$this->input->post('utype'),
        'token'=>$token,
        );

        $this->db->insert('tbl_user',$data);

        $email=$this->input->post('email');

        $config = array(
       'protocol'  => 'smtp',
       'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
       'smtp_port' => '465',
       'smtp_user' => 'someone@gmail.com',
       'smtp_pass' => 'something',
       'mailtype'  => 'html',
       'starttls'  => true,
       'newline'   => "\r\n"
       );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->From("someone@gmail.com");
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('test');
        $this->email->message("worked");
        $this->email->send();

        if($this->email->send()) {
            echo '<script>alert("Email sent successfully")</script>';
            } else {
        $this->email->print_debugger();
}




    }



}


?>
```

Comment: Use your $data array to populate a view. `$html = $this->load->view('path/to/view', $data, true);` The 3rd parameter tells it to return contents instead of sending it to he output buffer. Then just use the `$html` to populate the message (`$this->email->message($html)`).

Comment: what is your URL with `token`??

Answer (score 1):

To pass data along with a URL you can use URI segments.

In your situation the easiest thing to do would probably to be to use `GET` parameters. To use these you would output the link as normal and then append a parameter to the end like:

`http://yoursite.com/user/verify/**token**`

This example would be for if you had a `user` controller with a function called `verify`. The method signature would be something like:

```
public function verify($token = NULL) { ... }
```

The last part of the URL will populate `$token` which you can then use in the `verify` function to check the user is valid and perform any actions you need to.

You could always re-route a URL to an alternative method through `routes.php` if you needed to as well.

Simply pass this link with the token inserted into the email so that when the user clicks on it then the `verify` method runs with the necessary parameters.